# Среднее арифметическое узлов графа

Tags: javascript, рекурсия

Есть ф-я которая суммирует значения узлов графа

```
const average = graph => {
    const sum = graph => {
        const { value, children } = graph;
        return children
            ? children.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + sum(cur), value)
            : value;
    };

    return sum(graph);
};
```

Как узнать количество узлов графа для подсчета среднего арифметического
**(важно использовать только функциональное программирование)**

Comment: точно так же как и при суммировании, просто вместо value - надо считать количество узлов

Comment: @Grundy как это сделать за один обход графа

Comment: приведи пример графа, я поправлю код из вопроса

Answer (score 0):

```
const curry = reducer => {
    const walk = graph => {
        const { children } = graph;
        return children
            ? children.map(walk).reduce(reducer, { ...graph, count: 1 })
            : { ...graph, count: 1 };
    };
    return walk;
};

const average = graph => {
    const { value, count } = curry((acc, cur) => {
        return {
            value: acc.value + cur.value,
            count: acc.count + cur.count
        };
    })(graph);

    return value / count;
};
```